# Android Driver Event Listener like WebDriverEventListener

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm working with Selenium Webdriver, `Listener` and `MyEventListener` who implements `WebDriverEventListener`. This `MyEventListener` is register on `EventFiringWebDriver` like this:

```
EventFiringWebDriver myTestDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(
        web_driver);
myListener = new MyEventListener(this.getClass().getName());
myTestDriver.register(myListener);
driver = myTestDriver;
```

Now I must work with an `AndroidDriver` for mobile and I want the same structure. I have found the `AppiumWebDriverEventListener`. `MyEventListener implements AppiumWebDriverEventListener`, but now I can't make the same structure because the `EventFiringWebDriver` is not compatible with `AndroidDriver`. I try this:

```
myDriver = (AndroidDriver) new      BQAquarisDriver().returnDriver(driverPlace, new BQAquarisDriver());
EventFiringWebDriver myTestDriver = new
EventFiringWebDriver(myDriver);
myListener = new MyEventListener(this.getClass().getName());
myTestDriver.register(myListener);
myDriver = myTestDriver;
```

But does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Appium has this interface "**AppiumWebDriverEventListener**" which is the same as "**WebDriverEventListener**".

And you can find in [**this GitHub repository**](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/The-event_firing.md) everything about Appium Listeners, what interfaces to implement and how to use.

Comment: I know it spent a while but...this options was deprecated for Appium. Do you know any alternative?

Comment: Hi @j.barrio,
Just wrote an article for you :)
https://nael-marwan.medium.com/selenium-webdriverlistener-4f6889804256

Answer (score 1):

We can implement using `EventFiringWebDriverFactory`: https://appiumlistener.blogspot.com/

```
AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
driver = EventFiringWebDriverFactory.getEventFiringWebDriver(driver, new ActivityCapture());
```